# How to remove anchor hashtag from URL in Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a url containing a hash (http://localhost:3000/#submit-cv). On click the user scrolls to the relevant section on the page (which works fine). What i'm trying to do is remove the hash from the url once clicked.

I've tried a mixture of `window.location.href.split('#')[0]` and `console.log(this.$route.fullPath.split('#')[0]);`. The traditional window.location doesn't work with it being Nuxt. $route.fullPath with split returns the correct url values in console, but if I try and run the following nothing happens:

```js
removeHash() {
  this.$route.fullPath.split('#')[0]
}
```

I anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you do that? It's breaking one of the core things in HTML. It's not very semantic neither.

Comment: The user doesn't need to see it really as it's for an anchor link. Also by having the # in the url it breaks the active styling or nav links set by `linkExactActiveClass: 'active',` in `nuxt-config.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either:

- move to the anchor with some JS rather than using an HTML anchor link
- a custom active class for your style.

If you really want to do this in Vue, you can use

```js
// overrides the current URL with the actual part before the '#'
this.$router.push(this.$route.path.split('#'))
```

Could also use a `[0]` after the split but it may not even be required, to my testing at least.